# How do I implement drag and drop node re-ordering in a view?

Tags: views

I am creating a simple content admin view, and I need to implement drag and drop re-ordering (instead of weights in drop down menus). Is that possible, and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [Draggable Views](http://drupal.org/project/draggableviews) module:

> DraggableViews makes rows of a view "draggable" which means that they can be rearranged by Drag'n'Drop.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Nodequeue](http://drupal.org/project/nodequeue).  If you have [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) installed an enabled, you will get a view for each nodequeue if you have the settings configure appropriately.  I prefer this solution over DraggableViews.